# Does anyone know how to display a location in google map without using the latitude and longitude?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I need to display a list of locations on google map.

I have used google autocomplete to store the places name in the database, and now I need to display those same places in google map.

I know how to do it using the latitude and longitude, but not with places 'name

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.